# HEREWego in Tizen Application

Tags: tizen

I am creating Tizen application, from the Tizen application i am able to open HereWeGo application explicitly.

I want to pass coordinates and display routes when i request for Map from my application.

How to do it?

```
app_control_h a_control_inner = NULL;
app_control_create(&a_control_inner);
app_control_set_operation(a_control_inner, APP_CONTROL_OPERATION_DEFAULT);
app_control_set_app_id(a_control_inner, "com.here.tizen.herewego"); //        
app_control_set_uri(a_control_inner,"latitude:12.76333,longitude:80.003500000000003");
app_control_add_extra_data(a_control_inner, "latitude:12.76333", "longitude:80.003500000000003");
int applauch= app_control_send_launch_request(a_control_inner, loc_launch_cb, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to use Common Application Controls? https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/app-management/common-appcontrols/
You can find two types related with Maps.
- Showing a Location on a Map
- Picking a Location from the Map